# Testing in-app purchase after going live

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, live, sandbox

I would like to make a contest for my iPhone and iPad apps users. I would like to give some bonus content for winners as a reward. Normally that content is paid (for eg. additional levels) and it's available via in-app purchase, so I'm trying to find any way to give them something like normal promo codes. (Promo codes are not working with in-app purchase). Is that possible to set up Test Accounts for testing in app purchase after going live (my apps are already in the App Store), so I could configure them for winners? If not, what would be solution as an alternative for promo codes? Many review sites are asking for promo codes too, so answer would be helpful in other cases. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595122/workaround-to-lack-of-promotional-codes-for-in-app-purchases