# How to test in App purchase for an live app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I saw this question but its not what i need :- [Testing in-app purchase after going live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878117/testing-in-app-purchase-after-going-live)\

I want to provide limited set of testers free access to In App Purchase for testing purposes.The first version of app is live i wish to upload new version. What are my options?

I can make every thing free through code on development build and install it on testers device but i don't want to go this way.

Will the IAP test accounts work if one version of app is live already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Testing In-App purchase you have to login into your developer account and add Test user account for In-App purchase . Search for Sandbox In-App purchase testing and app you will get relevant steps.